# Simulate effect of confounder on two random variables

Tags: r, data-generation, causality

I want to generate some data in order to show partial correlation to control for a confounder.

Specifically, I want to generate data about two uncorrelated random variables (let's say speech and memory) and use a third variable to influence them both (age).

I'd expect to observe a strong correlation between speech and memory, due to the confounder age, and no correlation between the same two variables if I control for age (that is, calculate a partial correlation on age).

That said, I can't generate the strong correlation with my code.

```
age <- rep(1:10, 10)

speech <- age * abs(rnorm(100))
memory <- age * abs(rnorm(100))

cor(speech, memory) # correlation, it should be high but it's not

residuals_speech <- lm(speech ~ age)$residuals
residuals_memory <- lm(memory ~ age)$residuals

cor(residuals_speech, residuals_memory) # partial correlation controlling for age, it should be around zero
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random noise needs to be additive, not multiplicative:

```r
set.seed(1)

age <- rep(1:10, 10)

speech <- age + rnorm(100)
memory <- age + rnorm(100)
```

Now we have a high correlation between speech and memory:

```
cor(speech, memory)
#> [1] 0.9067772
```

But the correlation of the residuals once age is taken into account is close to zero, as expected.

```r
residuals_speech <- lm(speech ~ age)$residuals
residuals_memory <- lm(memory ~ age)$residuals

cor(residuals_speech, residuals_memory) 
#> [1] 0.0001755437
```

To get speech and memory to be on different scales with different amounts of noise (as real data might be), you can multiply `age` and the random noise by scalar values. This will retain the high correlation caused by the confounder.

```r
set.seed(1)

age <- rep(1:10, 10)

speech <- 5 * age + 3 * rnorm(100)
memory <- 2.1 * age - 2 * rnorm(100)

cor(speech, memory)
#> [1] 0.9361466

residuals_speech <- lm(speech ~ age)$residuals
residuals_memory <- lm(memory ~ age)$residuals

cor(residuals_speech, residuals_memory) 
#> [1] -0.0001755437
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>